# How can I add some IF statements with decimal variables?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a variable X which contains a decimal value. I want to write some IF conditions to match X to a dataframe.

Say I have X = 1.1 and a dataframe called OutputDF as below.

```
OutputDF
   score    ID
1    32     1.2
2    35     1.3
3    20     2.1
4    15     3.2
```

I want to write some IF conditions that works on decimals.

I want to include 3 conditions regarding this output.

C1. If 1.x is the only element print YES. 
In the above output we can see that 1.x is not the only element. There is 2.x and 3.x there as well.

C2. If 1.x is not the only element but 1.x has highest score print YES. 
In the sample we can see a 1.x contains highest score so this time it is a yes.

C3. If 1.x is not the only element but 1.x occurs most frequent print YES.
In the sample we can see that 1.x occurs 2 times vs the other elements so it is a yes.

So my expected output for the above sample is

```
ID  C1   C2   C3
1.1 NO   YES  YES
```

Comment: Could you add your expected output in a code-like format? The 1.xs and 2.xs make it difficult to follow.

Comment: *"if 1.x is the only element"* ... in the entire frame column? by part-before-dot? by part-after-dot? Where did ID 1.1 come from? Could you make your expected output match your offered input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional approach to get your expected output for any decimal value and any dataframe containing a variable `score` with values and a variable `ID` with decimal values:

```
FOO <- function(x, df){
  data.frame(ID = x,
             C1 = ifelse(all(trunc(df$ID) %in% trunc(x)), "YES", "NO"),
             C2 = ifelse(max(df$score[trunc(df$ID) %in% trunc(x)]) == max(df$score), "YES", "NO"),
             C3 = ifelse(which.max(table(trunc(df$ID))) == trunc(x), "YES", "NO"))
}
```

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(score = c(32,35,20,15),
                 ID = c(1.2,1.3,2.1,3.2))

FOO(1.1, df)

   ID C1  C2  C3
1 1.1 NO YES YES
```

Comment: I like this solution. But i modified the C3 because using table on single element df adds a 1 to it and screws with the result. So I used @Hunaidkhan mode function to get what i want. Also I wanted to ask is there a way to avoid false positives? I mean if max score is not unique and i want the condition to say YES only if x has highest score and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

Using Base R please find the answer

```
df <- read.table(text="   score    ID
1    32     1.2
2    35     1.3
3    20     2.1
4    15     3.2      ",header= T)
```

Answer :-

```
df$c1 <- ifelse(length(unique(substr(df$ID,1,1))) == 1,"Yes","No")

df$c2 <- ifelse((substr(df$ID,3,3)) == max(substr(df$ID,3,3)),"Yes","No")

# Create the function as Mode is not directly available in R ##
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}


df$c3 <- ifelse(substr(df$ID,1,1) == getmode(substr(df$ID,1,1)),"Yes","No")


result <- structure(list(score = c(32L, 35L, 20L, 15L), ID = c(1.2, 1.3, 
2.1, 3.2), c1 = c("No", "No", "No", "No"), c2 = c("No", "Yes", 
"No", "No"), c3 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
X <- c(1.1,1.2,2.4,3.5)
score<-c(5,4,3,2)
if(all(floor(X) ==1)) {
print('yes')
} else{
print('no' )}
if(any(score[floor(X)==1]==max(score))){
print('yes')
} else{
print('no' )}
if(as.numeric(names(table(floor(X)))[which(table(floor(X)) == max(table(floor(X)))) ]) 
 ==1){
print('yes')
} else{
print('no' )}
```